# Installing Oracle XE on Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, virtualbox, macbook, macbook-pro, oracle-11g

I wanted to install Oracle XE on my MacBook Pro. As of now, I have installed VirtualBox but not sure what else I should download and install. I got [Developer VM list](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html), but all seems to be huge in size. Could anyone suggest me steps by which I can have Oracle XE on my MacBook Pro without wasting unnecessary bandwidth.

Comment: Your confused about what Oracle XE package your suppose to install or which VirtualBox package?

Comment: which package to install for Oracle XE. First part of your question.

Comment: So edit your question to say that.  You should download which ever package makes the most sense, which contains Oracle XE, which one you want I can't answer.  There is no wrong answer.

Comment: Could you suggest manual steps (installing OS and Oracle db only), by which I can install what is needed that may not be listed in developer vm list.

Comment: Do I have the knowledge to provide, step-by-step instructions to install the Oracle Database XE, I absolutely do have that knowledge.  Do I feel it would make a good answer, to the question you have ask, I do not.  Just download a 64-bit Linux ,ISO, of the distribution of your choice, then install, [this]http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html).  Do your homework on what vulnerabilities exists on a 2 year old release though.

Comment: You are better off going with, the standard edition, of 12c Release 1.

Answer (score 1):

As of today I've managed to install Oracle Express Edition 18.4.0 on Mac using [docker](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/).

Also you can pick one of `11.2.0.2`, `12.1.0.2`, `12.2.0.1`, `18.3.0`,  `18.4.0`, `19.3.0` XE versions by supplying needed `-v` version to the `buildDockerImage.sh` script just like I did with `-v 18.4.0` in the example below.

Here's a full algo:

1. clone from github https://github.com/oracle/docker-images - it is a repo with official dockerfiles for easy start.
2. execute in a shell line by line:

```
    cd docker-images/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles

    ./buildDockerImage.sh -v 18.4.0 -x    

    docker run --name xe -p 1521:1521 -p 5500:5500 -e ORACLE_PWD=pick_your_password -e ORACLE_CHARACTERSET=AL32UTF8 oracle/database:18.4.0-xe
```

Done!

You can set your own password, ports and other settings when running container from the built image.

NOTE: Be aware the process of script execution may appear as stuck but actually it needs some time to download images because remote repo provides slow speed.

Full docs I studied it from: 
https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance

After each restart of your machine you can run again prepared XE docker container  using `docker start xe` command.